# ORA-30626: function/procedure parameters of remote object types are not supported

Tags: function, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, dblink

I am new to oracle technology, please help me

I couldn't find the answer any were. My task is to run two function's by passing parameter through dblink. I have two the same function on db1 and db2 which are located on two different virtual machine in hyper v, I managed to create dblink between them, but when I query the following command its displaying the above error msg.

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(4) */ *
FROM TABLE(my_fun(CURSOR(SELECT PDBID, STRUCTURE FROM PROTEINS
WHERE PDBID= '1n6h'),
  CURSOR(SELECT PDBID, STRUCTURE FROM PROTEINS WHERE PDBID BETWEEN
  '1n6h' AND '1n6h'), PRINT => 0, ALGORITHM_TYPE=>2, CHAIN2=>'A'))
 UNION ALL
  SELECT /*+ parallel(4) */ *
  FROM TABLE(my_fun@test_link2(CURSOR(SELECT PDBID, STRUCTURE FROM
   PROTEINS WHERE PDBID= '1n6h'),
   CURSOR(SELECT PDBID, STRUCTURE FROM PROTEINS WHERE PDBID BETWEEN
   '1n6n' AND '1n6n'), PRINT => 0, ALGORITHM_TYPE=>2, CHAIN2=>'A'));
```

This is what I created in both db1 and db2, I tried to create a wrapper function in both database's, but I still can't get the data through dblink.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
 type my_record force is object (
   QPDBID varchar2(8),
   DBPDBID varchar2(8));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE AS TABLE OF
my_record
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfun_rem(qpdb in varchar2,dbpdbid1 in varchar2)
    RETURN MY_TYPE
  AS
    v_my_tst MY_TYPE;
  BEGIN
SELECT MY_RECORD(QPDBID ,DBPDBID)
  BULK COLLECT INTO  v_my_tst
FROM
  (SELECT QPDBID, DBPDBID FROM TABLE(my_fun(CURSOR(SELECT PDBID,
    STRUCTURE FROM PROTEINS WHERE PDBID= QPDBID ),
      CURSOR(SELECT PDBID, STRUCTURE FROM PROTEINS WHERE PDBID BETWEEN
    QPDBID  AND QPDBID ), PRINT => 0, ALGORITHM_TYPE=>2, CHAIN2=>'A')));
    RETURN  v_my_tst;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_my_tst.DELETE;
    RETURN  v_my_tst;
  END;
  /

 SELECT * FROM  TABLE(myfun_rem(param1,param2)); --this works locally but not remotely (select * from table(myfun_rem@test_link(param1,param2))

SELECT * FROM  TABLE(myfun_loc(param1,param2))
union all
SELECT * FROM  TABLE(myfun_rem@test_link(param1,param2,parm3));
```

--not working the same error message as above

I tried to create view in remote db2 but no data is displaying as my function needs parameters to be passed, which is impossible to pass parameter in view.

p.s sorry for my poor English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a stored function (that returns an array of a user-defined type) in oracle across a database link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245995/calling-a-stored-function-that-returns-an-array-of-a-user-defined-type-in-orac)

Comment: Hi, have you checked my **edit** in the answer?

Comment: yes i did check your edited answer , i was trying to use your example in my problem even tough i'm still not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have dealt with this situation, your best way is to serialize the table of objects in db1 and convert them back to table of objects in db2

1- your object should have a serialization function which converts its fields into string.

2- your object should have a constructor with ability to initialize a new object from string.

for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CAR AS OBJECT
    (NAME VARCHAR2 (36),
     MODEL NUMBER,
     MEMBER FUNCTION SERIALIZE
         RETURN VARCHAR2,
     MEMBER FUNCTION DUMP
         RETURN VARCHAR2,
     STATIC FUNCTION DESRIALIZE (DATA IN VARCHAR2)
         RETURN CAR);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CAR
IS
    MEMBER FUNCTION SERIALIZE
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
    --YOU HAVE TO CONVERT ALL FIELDS(TYPE MEMBERS) TO STRING HERE(USE FIELD SEPARATOR LIKE ',')
    BEGIN
        RETURN NAME || ',' || TO_CHAR (MODEL, 'FM9999');
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION DUMP
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN    'CAR NAME: ['
               || NAME
               || ']'
               || CHR (10)
               || CHR (13)
               || 'CAR MODEL: ['
               || TO_CHAR (MODEL, 'FM9999')
               || ']';
    END;

    STATIC FUNCTION DESRIALIZE (DATA IN VARCHAR2)
        RETURN CAR
    IS
        --DO EXACTLY REVERSE OF SERIALIZATION
        NEW_CAR   CAR;
    BEGIN
        NEW_CAR :=
            CAR (SUBSTR (DATA, 1, INSTR (DATA, ',') - 1),
                 TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (DATA, INSTR (DATA, ',') + 1)));
        --TO_NUMBER FUNCTION IS NOT REALLY NEEDED HERE, ORACLE DOES THE CAST FOR YOU, BUT I TRIED  TO MAKE IT MORE UNDERSTANDABLE
        RETURN NEW_CAR;
    END;
END;

DECLARE
    MY_CAR     CAR;
    V_STRING   VARCHAR2 (64);
    DUP_CAR    CAR;
BEGIN
    MY_CAR := CAR ('PEYKAN', 1350);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (MY_CAR.DUMP ());
    V_STRING := MY_CAR.SERIALIZE ();--You should do this in db 1 and send string(varchar2) to db2
    DUP_CAR := CAR.DESRIALIZE (V_STRING);--In db2, you will do this to get the object from string
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DUP_CAR.DUMP ());
END;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer hmmftg, as i mentioned above this is my first time in oracle,could you give me simple example code for your answer.