# Returning Multiple Values from Oracle Function over Database Link

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, types, database-link

I have two oracle databases: A and B.
On database A, I have a function which returns user defined type:

```
create or replace type my_type as object
     ( id number,
        f2 varchar2(4000),
        f3 varchar2(4000),
        f4 varchar2(4000)
      );
```

and

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(p_id NUMBER)   
      RETURN my_type IS   
      v_f1 VARCHAR2;   
      v_f2 VARCHAR2;   
      v_f3 VARCHAR2; 
    BEGIN
    
      SELECT a.f1, a.f2, a.f3
           INTO v_f1, v_f2, v_f3   
      FROM my_table a  
      WHERE a.id= p_id;
    
      RETURN my_type (p_id, v_f1, v_f2, v_f3);
    
    END my_function;
```

When I call this function from Oracle A it returns

[image]

BUT, when I call it from Oracle B it throws ERROR:

> ORA-30626: function/procedure parameters of remote object types are not supported

Can you tell me, how to get my SQL query results(f1, f2, f3) from database A to database B.
I don't want to call the query thrice, because of the performance issue.

The only solution I came up was to concatenate these three fields in one value on database A and then substring it on database B, do you have any better idea?

Comment: Does the data have to come from a function? Could you instead use a procedure with four OUT parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Your object "my_type" should have "SERIALIZE" & "DESRIALIZE" functionality, then you should be able to call your function "my_function()" remotely without an error.

See also this question:
[ORA-30626: function/procedure parameters of remote object types are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813673/ora-30626-function-procedure-parameters-of-remote-object-types-are-not-supporte)

And the oracle doc:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jpl2-serial.html